# Prove that $[0,1]$ isn't homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove that $[0,1]$ isn't homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

My first thought is that there can not be a continuous bijection, $f$, from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ because a continuous function that maps $[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ must be bounded so there can't be a surjection. So that would then be the proof.

Though I believe I am incorrect in my thinking because a hint for the assignment says to use the intermediate value theorem. That is "Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. If $f(a)<\delta<f(b)$ or $f(b)<\delta<f(a)$ then $\delta=f(c)$ for some $c\in[a,b]$".

Why is my first thought wrong and how is the IVT useful?

Comment: One of them is compact and the other is not.

Comment: Your proof is fine; it’s basically the one suggested by **Michael Hardy**.

Comment: That's probably the most obvious way to see it. This is essentially the idea behind your boundedness idea. Another: Remove an endpoint from $[0,1]$, and it is still connected, whereas you cannot remove a point from $\mathbb{R}$ and still have it be connected.

Comment: I'm also curious as to what the hint-writer had in mind, using the IVT. There are many possible proofs of this fact, some more efficient than others, and some shedding light on different aspects of the situation than others. The IVT, topologically, says that the continuous image of a connected set is connected, and since both $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are connected, it's not obvious to me how that's useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to use the IVT: Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0, 1]$ is a continuous bijection. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(a)=0$; now look at $x=a-1$ and $y=a+1$. Since $f$ is injective, we have $f(x), f(y)\not=0$; let $0<c<\min\{f(x), f(y)\}$. By IVT, we have $f(x')=c$ for some $x<x'<a$ and $f(y')=c$ for some $a<y'<y$; but then $x'\not=y'$ but $f(x')=f(y')$, so $f$ is not injective. Contradiction.

Comment: Basically, this is just the connectivity argument G Tony Jacobs gives, but phrased using IVT.

Comment: How do I use IVT when I have a function of the form  $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R\{1}} $ and I want to show that it is not homeomorphic?

Answer (score 7):

The image of a compact space under a continuous function is compact.  If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ were a homeomorphism between $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R$, then $\mathbb R$ would be compact.

Comment: What specific objection does the down-voter have? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 5):

You can remove two points from $[0,1]$ without disconnecting it. That's not true of $\mathbb{R}$.

Your first thought wasn't wrong, and I don't know what the hint is getting at. This is just another proof, demonstrating that multiple proofs exist.

Comment: No need for two: use one.

Comment: Or you could use two. You see a little more of the structure of $[0,1]$ that way, and how far it is from being homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. I didn't claim I was presenting the strongest or most efficient proof.

Answer (score 3):

Compactness is a topological property. Topological properties are preserved under homeomorphism. With that in mind, no homeomorphism exists between $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$, because $[0,1]$ is compact, $\mathbb{R}$ is not.